# Proving that a quadratic form has a single eigenvalue in an open interval

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, quadratic-forms

I need help with this exercise:

> Show that the matrix
> B =\begin{pmatrix}
> 3 & 2 & 1 \\
> 2 & 4 & 1 \\
> 1 & 1 & 1
> \end{pmatrix}
>
> has exactly one eigenvalue in the open interval (1,2) by studying the signatures of the quadratic forms with matrices $B-I$ and $B-2I$.

The only thing I have managed to do is compute the signatures of $B-I$ and $B-2I$. They're (2,1) and (1,2) respectively. I don't know how the open interval comes into play.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** For a scalar $\alpha$, the eigenvalues of $B - \alpha I$ are of the form $\lambda_i - \alpha$ for each eigenvalue $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ of $B$. On the other hand, the signatures tell you that $B - (1)I$ has $2$ positive eigenvalues while $B - 2I$ has $1$ positive eigenvalue.

Comment: I have been thinking along those lines, but I can't seem to get to the finish line. So, when you subtract another 1 from the eigenvalues of B, one of them turns negative. What then?

Comment: @Iain So, there has to be an eigenvalue such that $\lambda_i - 1 > 0$ and $\lambda_i - 2 < 0$. That is, $\lambda_i > 1$ and $\lambda_i < 2$, which is exactly what we want.

Comment: @Iain What do you mean "all of the eigenvalues are equal"? The thing that we are trying to show in this problem is that, for one of the eigenvalues (which I call $\lambda_i$ in my comment), it holds that the eigenvalue is in the open interval $(1,2)$.